# How can i using bubble sorting to sort the minimum to the front in python?

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I'm studying Python and I want to apply it while I'm studying bubble sorting. But I can't think of anything.

Given array **arr** and array size **n**, I want to implement it so that the only minimum value comes to arr[0] using bubble.

ex) arr = [4, 2, 3, 1, 5], n = 5,

[4, 2, 3, 1, 5] -> [4, 2, 1, 3, 5] -> [4, 1, 2, 3, 5] -> [1, 4, 2, 3, 5] -> **[1, 4, 2, 3, 5]**

return : [1, 4, 2, 3 ,5]

it doesn't working... :(

```
def bubbling(arr, n):
    tmp = min(arr)
    index = arr.index(tmp)

    for i in range(index):
        for j in range(n):
            if arr[index] > arr[index - 1]:
                arr[index], arr[index-1] = arr[index-1], arr[index]

    return arr

bubbling([45, 67, 82, 34, 21, 55], 6))
```

Comment: Aside: calling `min(arr)` isn't part of a bubble sort, you are doing a selection sort

Comment: That is not a Bubble sort. The simplest form of a Bubble sort just uses two loops based on the length of the list being processed. Not sure how you think *range(index)* is going to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no need to pass the list length to the sort function as it can be determined from the list itself.

Bubble sort (notwithstanding its inherent inefficiency) can be optimised. However, this is the classic implementation with no attempt to optimise.

```
def bubble(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(lst)):
            if lst[i] > lst[j]:
                lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified it. Is this right?

```
def bubbling(arr, n):
    len = n - 1
    for i in range(len):
        for j in range(len - i, 0, -1):
            if arr[j] < arr[j - 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j - 1] = arr[j - 1], arr[j]
                if arr[0] == min(arr):
                    break

    return arr


bubbling([45, 67, 82, 34, 21, 55], 6))
```

Comment: This does not sort the list